# C# - What object type is FormData

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a little form that will allow users to upload one file. The form is as below.

```
<form action="/Interviews/Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="createInterviewForm" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label>File Upload:</label>
        <input type="file" id="txtInterviewUploadFile"> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <input type="submit" value="Cancelar" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCancelInterviewCreation" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm uploading the file through ajax so I have the following code

```
$("form#createInterviewForm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var fd = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Interviews/AjaxCreate',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

On my controller I have something like this

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AjaxCreate(??What datatype??  postedData)
{
    return Json(true);
}
```

**The Question**
When I submit, the post reaches my controler. My problem here is I cant seem to figure out what is the object type of the FormData. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: usually you create a model that represents that formdata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i finally got this to work. This is what i did:

On the ajax i have the following:

```
$("form#createInterviewForm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        formData.append('file', $("#txtInterviewUploadFile")[0].files[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Interviews/AjaxCreate",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data)
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

This will post all form inputs and the file input.

On the controller all I had to do is use the Request.Form["Key"] and the Request.Files to access all the information

Comment: Can you provide an example of how it looks at controller side?

Comment: to get the file in the controller, you can just access using something like var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];. To get a property, you can use for example Request.Form["Name"]

Answer (score 0):

Check out `HttpPostedFileBase`. [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
(From MSDN) Serves as the base class for classes that provide access to individual 
files that have been uploaded by a client.
```

Your controller action would be:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AjaxCreate(HttpPostedFileBase postedData)
{
    return Json(true);
}
```

Comment: I changed my controller to match what you posted but postedData is null.